# Best CW Low Cut & High Cut Slope Settings on the Yaesu FT-991A?

Tags: cw, transceiver, yaesu

I am running a Yaesu FT-991A and am wondering which low and high cut slope settings would be the better to use on CW mode as far as making sure I don't get key clicks. The default menu # 051 = CW LCUT FREQ is 18db/octave = (18 decibels per octave) and default menu # 052 = CW HCUT FREQ is also 18db/octave. The only other menu choice is 6db/octave. Which would be the best setting to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am certain that this adjustable filter is **for reception only**.

Note that the Yaesu FT-991A operating manual describes settings 051 and 052 under a section titled “Adjustable **Receiver** Audio Filter”. I haven't used the FT-991A myself, but every radio I have used has similar settings for CW mode.

The filter will have no effect on your transmitted signal; you should adjust it to whatever settings you find suitable for listening.

Comment: Thanks for that info Kevin! Very much appreciated!

Comment: @Cliff-KU4GW You're welcome. If (and only if) you're entirely satisfied with this answer, please click the checkmark to “accept” it — that indicates that you're not looking for more answers.